# How can I have a div in which to put a message that breaks and does not go outside the div?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a message displayed in Html

right now I have

```
f'<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; line-height: 200px;">{message}</div>'
```

The problem is if this message is too long, the rest of the message will appear outside and invade other elements space

Ideally I want something like

[image]

How should I modify the html?

I have tried

```
 noplot_message=f'<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; word-wrap: break-word; display: inline-block; line-height: 200px;">{message}</div>'

       noplot_message=f'<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; word-wrap: break-word;overflow-wrap: break-word ; word-break: break-word;line-height: 200px;">{message}</div>'
```

but it has not worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS property **overflow** with the value **hidden** to hide the overflow content. Additionally, you can use **word-wrap:break-word;** Can set. Allowing long words to be broken up and wrapped to the next line.

```
noplot_message = f'<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; line-height: 1.5;">{message}</div>'
```

Answer (score 1):

To get required result, the following HTML code can be used:

```
<div style="width: 200px; min-height: 200px;  border: 1px solid black; word-break: break-word;line-height:1.5; padding: 50px 20px;">{message}</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).